# How to drag a button in a horizontal stack view

Tags: swift, xcode, button, drag-and-drop

I am new to Swift and working in Xcode. Here is my issue. I have a horizontal stack view with numbers out of order. My goal is to make the buttons draggable to reorder the numbers to be in numerical order. [UserScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkxCd.png). From what I have looked up, I should use a Pan Gesture Recognizer, but I do not know how to use it for buttons. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a `UIStackView` is the correct view type to be using for this. You could probably fight the API and get something working, but the way to achieve what you want is to probably use something like a `UICollectionView` as it has APIs for reordering the views (cells) that it is showing.

I think you'd find more help on the internet for using a collection view that way as well.

Comment: Ahhhh okay. Thank you so much; I will try that out and hope that it works!